# How to simulate drag in monkeyrunner with "Pressure"

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

Development.apk->"Pointer location" log:

```
03-02 17:22:28.050: I/Pointer(24911): Pointer 1: DOWN (400.0, 700.0) Pressure=0.0 Size=0.0 TouchMajor=0.0 TouchMinor=0.0 ToolMajor=0.0 ToolMinor=0.0 Orientation=0.0deg VScroll=0.0 HScroll=0.0
```

The Pressure when simulating "drag" using monkeyrunner is always 0.0.
How to add pressure?

- I am trying to simulate the scroll flick in the Browser. I appreciate any hints.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyDevice, MonkeyRunner, MonkeyView, MonkeyImage

my_device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
my_device.drag((350,600),(50,600),0.05,50)  #dragging screen to right
```

This will drag the screen to the right.
Starting coordinates: x1=350 y1=600
Finishing coordinates: x2=50 y2=600